# Regex select between nth special character and a string

Tags: regex, grep, esxi

I have an ESXi host that failed and I am trying to grep the guests that might have been running on the host at the time of failure.

I found some logs where the VM failed to load after we've powered back on the ESXi host, this could possibly give me the information I am looking for, however, I am only interested in the VM name and compiling it into a list.

One section of the log reads as:

```
2021-09-06T13:33:01.272Z info hostd[2101147] [Originator@6876 sub=Vmsvc.vm:/vmfs/volumes/5c0ae3ca-926257bb-d4dc-1234567e66bc/VMNAME/VMNAME.vmx] Failed to load virtual machine: N3Vim5Fault12FileNotFound9ExceptionE(Fault cause: vim.fault.FileNotFound
```

My end goal would be to grab "VMNAME" where this would be the names of all the virtual machine as there are several entries all with different names of course. Below is what I have so far, except I would like to select the 5th `/`

`(?=\/).*(?=.vmx)`

However, the above pattern returns no results, may be a limitation of ESXi, below is what I'm using to find the logs I need.

`grep -E "vim.fault" hostd.log`

If I have to paste the results of grep into np++ for a proper regex then that is fine also.
Any of your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: POSIX ERE does not support lookarounds. Try `grep -oE '[^][/]+\.vmx' hostd.log`. Or `sed -nE 's,.*/([^][/]+\.vmx).*,\1,p' hostd.log`

Comment: This is great, compiled exactly what I was looking for. Still had to use np++ to remove duplicate lines but nonetheless I got what I needed, thank you Wiktor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX ERE does not support lookarounds.

You can use

```sh
grep -oE '[^][/]+\.vmx' hostd.log
```

Here, `o` option makes `grep` extract matches, `E` enables the POSIX ERE syntax and the `[^][/]+\.vmx` regex matches one or more chars other than `]`, `[` and `/` and then `.vmx` substring.

Or, alternatively, `sed` like

```sh
sed -nE 's,.*/([^][/]+\.vmx).*,\1,p' hostd.log
```

Here,

- `-nE` - `n` option suppresses the default line output and `E` enables the POSIX ERE syntax
- `s,.*/([^][/]+\.vmx).*,\1,p` - `s`ubstitution command that finds

  - `.*` - any text
  - `/` - `/` char
  - `([^][/]+\.vmx)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `[`, `]` and `/` and then `.vmx`
  - `.*` - any text
- `\1` - replaces the match (the whole string) with Group 1 value
- `p` - only prints the result of the replacement.